# Is StepExecutionContext and Writer instance variables are thread safe in Spring Batch?

Tags: thread-safety, spring-batch

I am deriving a value in the Step listener and sharing the same in Itemwriter through StepExecutionContext. If there are multiple instances running for that job, is it thread safe having those params (SPECIFIC FOR THAT JOB) Spring Batch's StepExecutionContext ?

Another Question - I have a counter variable as an instance variable in the Itemwriter and increment the same in the write(). Will this counter var be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is more than thread-safety.

If you want to have single instance of reader/writer/listener, you gotta make sure it is stateless.

If you need to keep state in those artifact, you gotta make sure it is going to be a new instance for every job execution, one of the way is to declare them as step scoped.

Comment: Yeah, my StepListener, Reader and writer are "Step" scoped. So, this shouldn't be an issue. correct?

Comment: It should be fine.  For step-scoped bean, a new instance will be created for each step execution.  If you are not using any parallel processing feature of Spring Batch, then there should not be any thread-safety issue as only 1 thread will be calling your artifacts

Comment: Have you managed to do so? I am having some thread-safty issues when executing jobs in parallel

Comment: There should be no problem when executing multiple job in parallel. However if your step itself is a parallel step that may be a concern for you. It is hard to guess your problem. I will suggest you properly raise a question again.